# Show my current location in Google API 10 for Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, sdk

I'm having problem with showing my current location in this code. Can you please tell me how to add code that will zoom and show my current location.

```
public class MapaActivity extends MapActivity
{

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {

 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.mapa);

 MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
 mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

 List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
 Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
 HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);

 GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(44900101,14839100);
 OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Pin","Test pin");

 itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);



 mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
```

Comment: Can you show me the logcat error message

Comment: Try for LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER instead of LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER

Comment: i added it like this 
List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
 Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
 HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);
 
 LocationManager locationManager;
 locationManager=(LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
 Location location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
 GeoPoint point=new GeoPoint((int)(location.getLatitude()*1E6),(int)(location.getLongitude()*1E6));
 OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "hi","you are here");

Comment: Are your settings checked for wireless network. Go to settings--> Location & Security--> Use GPS Satellite check it. Also gove mock location in DDMS--> Emulator Control

Comment: same... can I send you full source code on mail so you can easy fix it?

Comment: you can mail me to the id provided in my stackoverflow profile.

Comment: I can't find it. send me mail on kristijandraca gmail.com and I will send you source

Comment: please see 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/12592673/1233606

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your GeoPoint you can use:

```
LocationManager locationManager;
        locationManager=(LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        GeoPoint point=new GeoPoint((int)(location.getLatitude()*1E6),(int)(location.getLongitude()*1E6));
```

And at the end add:

```
 mapView.getController().animateTo(point);
```

In the Manifest file add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```